# Is it possible to restrict an input field (UITextView) to a particular pattern?

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextview

I have a UITextView that I'd like to let the user enter tags in this pattern:

> #these #are #four      #tags

and the above would be a valid input.

The following below would be bad input:

> # this is #wrong ##formatting #bad#

Those are just some sample wrong cases that I came up with now, but the idea is to restrict the allowable input to the former example and then show an alert to re-enter otherwise.

Is there a way to accomplish this?  thank you!

Comment: You can simply allow the user to enter what he wants without "#" and then divide the string at every space and create a tag of them

Comment: I want to enforce putting the #tag because I'm also planning to use an autosuggest popup for existing tags.  The library Im using requires the # to be in front of the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the delegate method `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:`

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range  replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSMutableString *newText = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textView.text];
    [newText replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

    NSArray *tags = [newText componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    for (NSString *tag in tags) {
        if ([tag length] > 0 && ![tag hasPrefix:@"#"]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I believe there is a cleaner way using Regular expression than looping over the text

Comment: I ended up using something similar to this.  It works, but perhaps the regex method is better.

Answer (score 1):

Yep sure. You can use regex to restrict text inputs to ones that fit a particular pattern.

Apple NSRegularExpression Class Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

NSRegularExpression Tutorial and Cheat Sheet:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/

Comment: While I expect this is the actual right answer, I couldnt figure out the regex to make it work...